# How to zoom at center in scroll viewer while using ZoomToFactor to increase zoom level in button click

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, scrollviewer, zooming

I am using scroll viewer to zoom the image which is set as background for Grid.When, I am setting the zoom factor value on button click from code behind with  scrollViewer.ZoomToFactor(zoomFactor) image is getting zoomed from Top left corner ,not from the center position.

Please get the sample from the below link or below code snippet for your reference.
Link: https://github.com/ragulsv/ScrollViewer

Code Snippet[C#]:

```
    float count = 1;
    private void Clr_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        count = 1;
         viewer.ZoomToFactor(count);
        viewer.RenderTransformOrigin = new Point(0.5, 0.5);
    }
    private void Btn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
         viewer.ZoomToFactor(count);
        viewer.RenderTransformOrigin = new Point(0.5, 0.5);
        count += 1;
    }
```

Code Snippet[Xaml]:

```
   <Grid x:Name="grid1">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="0.1*">

        </RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition Height="0.1*">

        </RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition Height="0.8*">

        </RowDefinition>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Button x:Name="btn" Grid.Row="0"></Button>
    <Button x:Name="clr" Grid.Row="1"></Button>
    <ScrollViewer x:Name="viewer" Grid.Row="2" ZoomMode="Enabled">
        <Grid>
          <Image Source="Assets\EditedImage.jpg" Height="190" Width="190"/>
        </Grid>
    </ScrollViewer>
</Grid>
```

Comment: did you try setting the `RenderTransformOrigin` to "0.5,0.5" ?

Comment: Even, I tried 'RenderTransformOrigin' to "0.5,0.5". It also not working .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How to zoom at center in scroll viewer while using ZoomToFactor to increase zoom level in button click

For this scenario, you could set Image's parent `Grid` `VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"` that could make the image always fix on the center of  `ScrollViewer` and then call ChangeView method to edit `ZoomFactor`.

```
private void Btn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    viewer.ChangeView(0, 0, (viewer.ZoomFactor + 1f));       
}
```

Comment: Thanks,I even tried this method too. It is not working.

Comment: I have upload sample [here](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AlLBgdBasvMrgYYEm4s4pixvRD8mkg?e=ErYupd), please check.

Comment: Thanks,Sample gets working as I expect. But,I want to get clear that image gets center only of setting horizontal and vertical alignment for grid as center.

Comment: But the image gets center even if we zoom ScrollViewer with editing ZoomToFactor value by setting grid vertical and horizontal alignment as center. Can you check it and update your answer. I will [mark](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235) it after you update it.

Comment: I found `VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"` make it work. I need edit the complete answer.